# How to draw a custom rectangle with border radius in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, draw, shapes

My UI draw like this picture:
[image]

So I write some code by using CodePainter in Flutter. Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackgroundShape extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.black;
    var smallRect = Alignment.bottomCenter.inscribe(Size(100, 50), Rect.fromLTWH(size.width/2 -35, size.height-40, 40, 30));
    var path = Path();
    path.fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
    path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)));
    path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(smallRect, topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10)));
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2 - 35, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2 - 35, size.height-40);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2 + 35, size.height-40);
    path.lineTo(size.width/2 + 35, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Here is my result:
[image]

How to add border radius? please help me :D thanks!

Comment: use `Path.addRRect()` method

Comment: @pskink this method actually didn't help me

Comment: yes it does, it adds rounded rectangle, the docs say: *"Adds a new sub-path that consists of the straight lines and curves needed to form the rounded rectangle described by the argument."*

Comment: @pskink I know but how about middle small rectangle?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/fillType.html

Comment: @pskink Sorry, I can't solve my problem

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink That is okey thank you :D I am solve this issue by using Stack and Container widgets

Comment: no, no, no, this is a bad, ugly workaround - you can do that in just two `Path.addRRect` method calls

Comment: @pskink I think so I really want to use CustomPainter but I can't use addRRect. are you know some solution? I already attached code above. please help me

Comment: @pskink I already edited

Comment: I am sorry I didn't notice this code that's working thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I'm not able to run completely the code you've provided, but taking consideration your current requirements and from the comments. I've created the following samples for your references:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: PainterTwo(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PainterOne extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;
    double r = 15;

    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0xff888888)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    RRect fullRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(w / 2, h / 2), width: w, height: h),
      Radius.circular(r),
    );
    canvas.drawRRect(fullRect, paint1);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class PainterTwo extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(
            size.width / 2, size.height / 2, size.width / 4, size.height / 4),
        Radius.circular(15)));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Output of PainterOne():

[image]

Output of PainterTwo():

[image]